# Siesta Integration

Tags: tomcat, selenium, web-testing, siesta

Is there any way/idea to implement Siesta Code in Tomcat? Or, How to deploy siesta examples in Tomcat ?

I have Lots of tests.js Files in project, have to include that in my code

Answer (score 1):

Siesta examples are plain javascript files - you can deploy them in the same way you deploy static files. Sorry, I can't provide more details as I don't have much experience with Tomcat.